# ¿Cómo evitar la impresión de número de una ruta URL - PHP?

Tags: php

Mediante un `array` tengo la posibilidad de cambiar el nombre de un valor de una `URL` ejemplo: `/belleza/` por `Productos de Belleza` eso sí, el enlace concerva su valor es decir `example.com/belleza/`  y eso está bien, es correcto.

```
<?php
$trail = array(
   'es' => '',
   'mujer' => 'Articulos de Mujer',
   'belleza' => 'Productos de Belleza'
);

 $url = '/es/belleza/mujer/2018/04/08/perfume-de-mujer-2 ';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    // sólo añadir al breadcrumb si el valor del enlace no está vacío
    if ($value != "") {
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value)) . '</a>';
    }
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', 
$path['filename']));
//$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);
array_pop($breadcrumbs);
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;

?>
```

Resultados:

> Home » Productos de Belleza » Artículos de Mujer » 2018 » 04 » 08

También tengo la posibilidad, de que si reemplazo un valor de la `URL` con un calor vacío, este no me imprime ese dato, porque está vacío, es en el caso del valor de la URL de `/es/` como pueden observar no sé imprimió en el resultado.

De la misma manera podría hacerlo con las fechas que se encuentra en la `URL` `/2018/04/08/` mediante el `array` dándole un valor vacío.

```
$trail = array(
   'es' => '',
   '2018' => '',
   '04' => '',
   '08' => '',
   'belleza' => 'Productos de Belleza'
);
```

El problema de eliminar la impresión de las fechas, mediante el `array` es que tengo que añadirle los 31 días del mes, los 12 meses del año, y todos los años que siguen.

Existe una forma, una condición, para evitar que me imprime las fechas `/2018/04/08` de la `URL` para así tener el siguiente resultado de impresión

> Home » Productos de Belleza » Artículos de Mujer

Comment: Hola Fernando! Me parece que estás mezclando dos pedidos. Por un lado, podrías querer modificar la URL para que no aparezca la fecha allí. Por el otro, podrías querer modificar los breadcrumbs. No es necesario hacer lo primero para lograr lo segundo. Estás seguro de que querés hacer ambas cosas? Perfectamente podrías poner una condición que verifique si estás trabajando con un número y que no lo agregue a los breadcrumbs.

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz Hola :) no la `URL` que traigo no quiero modificarla, todo esas modificaciones que lo realice el `breadcrumbs` que mi sistema sea el encargado de ello sin tener que pasarle otros parámetros a la `URL` todo sea manejado por el sistema `breadcrumbs` así como cumple la función el `array` algo similar que pueda evitar aparecer las fechas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es detectar lo siguiente:

```
if ($value != "" && !preg_match('/^\d{1,4}$/', $value)) {
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value)) . '</a>';
    }
```

Esto lo que hace es detectar si $value es un string que contiene entre 1 y 4 dígitos numéricos. Si no es el caso, hace lo que hacía hasta ahora.

Actualizacion: corregido el error mencionado en los comentarios

Comment: Hola @VictoriaRuiz su ejemplo me muestra el siguiente error: `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in `

Comment: corresponde a esta linea de código `if ($value != "" && !preg_match('^\d{1,4}$', $value)) {`

Comment: ya lo solucione y agregue más valores a la vez `'/^\d{1,8}$/'` funciona de maravilla, mil gracias amiga :)

Comment: Me alegra que funcione, @fernando. Ya corregí el error que mencionabas en la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad al usar `array_key_exists` ya puedes descartar los elementos que no están en tu array de reemplazo:

```
<?php

$url = '/es/belleza/mujer/2018/04/08/perfume-de-mujer-2 ';

$parts = parse_url($url);

$trail_map = [
    'mujer'   => 'Articulos de Mujer',
    'belleza' => 'Productos de Belleza',
];

$segments = explode('/', $parts['path']);
$crumb_path='';
$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';

foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail_map)) ? $trail_map[$segment] : null;
    if (!is_null($value)) {
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value)) . '</a>';
    }
}

$breadcrumbs = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;
```

No tiene sentido aplicar un `array_pop` para quitar `perfume-de-mujer-2` porque dado que no existe en el array, no se incluirá en el breadcrumb.

**NOTA** esta solución implica que llenes el `$trail_map` con todas tus categorías y subcategorías, que es algo que debieses tener en tu base de datos.

**NOTA2** si tienes una url en donde el nombre del artículo es igual al nombre de una categoría, vas a tener problemas.

Si estás usando alguna clase de CMS con urls amigables, como Wordpress, puedes obtener el slug del post y quitarlo del final de la cadena cuando la url apunte a un post.

Comment: No funciona amigo, recuerde que en el `array` es el remplazo del titulo por otro siempre en cuando yo lo desee, ahora visite una url que no tiene parametros en el `array` y solo me imprime **Home**

Comment: Quizá podrías editar tu pregunta explicando cuándo lo deseas y cuando no. Mi respuesta se basó en una suposición dada la falta de información.